# Find largest directories/files recursively

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

I'm looking for a script/program which will display the top *x* largest directories/files and then descend into those folders and display the *x* largest directories/files for a configurable depth.

```
231MB bin
 - 220MB ls
  - 190MB dir
  - 15MB def
  - 3MB lpr
 - 10MB asd
 - 1MB link
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 23):

You can see the 10 largest directories with:

```
du -cks *|sort -rn|head
```

This will recursively add up the sizes of everything in each directory - but you would have to manually execute it at each level to get a breakdown of what's in each

Answer (score 11):

Chances are your system has one of these installed or available through your package manager:

Graphical:

- [Baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) - aka Disk Usage Analyzer - Gnome (Applications>Accessories or Applications>System Tools)
- [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) - KDE
- [Filelight](http://www.methylblue.com/filelight/) - KDE
- [TreeSize](http://treesize.sourceforge.net/) for Unix - GTK2

Text-based:

- [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) - ncurses
- [gt5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/) - text browser (lynx, w3m, etc. - auto-selected) - It's actually a shell script!

They may not work exactly as you specified, but they should do most of what you need.

Comment: `ncdu` is awesome!

Answer (score 7):

My variation on Brent's answer is:

```
# du -a | sort -rn | head
```

Which will give you the largest directories or files in the tree.

Comment: I would add the -h option to get better printed results for the size.

Comment: You can't add -h as then you'd end up with 2M being higher than 1G.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got this far myself, but got stuck on recursion :-)

Comment: GNU sort also supports the -h option.

Answer (score 3):

You could do some similar using find:

```
# find -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec du -sh {} \;
```

But this won't be sorted by size and will be incredible slow and inefficient. Better off writing a script that parses du -a.

Comment: there is a typo, this command should be : find **.** -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec du -sh {} \;

Answer (score 3):

This gets you the sorted human-readable size of the top 10 largest files/folders in the entire directory tree:

```
du -ah | sort -hr | head
```

Example

```
1019M   .
431M    ./prod
195M    ./prod/mainprogram
180M    ./utils
162M    ./prod/subprogram1
157M    ./.git
156M    ./py
155M    ./.git/objects
148M    ./.git/objects/pack
128M    ./prod/mainprogram/hdf
```

Answer (score 2):

(Wanted to add this as a comment to Brent's answer but dont see a link to do that)
I recently had a similar problem, and if you need to just check one partition in question, adding a -x to Brent's answer is pretty useful, especially if some directories have their own partition.

So it would be:

```
du -ckx / | sort -rn | head
```

Answer (score 1):

> Something to remember about human-readable output is that a reverse numeric sort won't work as expected without fixing it up.  A quicker option is to use the -k switch to output the directory size information in kilobytes.

I'd have a short look into the manpage of sort - on some systems you can use `sort -h` to sort human-readable output. I've used this on CentOS 6.2 with sort 8.4. Otherwise you can redirect the output of `du -h` to a file and sort that with something like:

```
for i in K M G; do egrep "^[0-9,\.]+${i}" somefile | sort -n; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a command-line tool that does this (other than what the other answers have suggested), but if you are able to run GUI programs on this machine, try [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/). It shows the disk usage of all files and directories under a particular root, sorted by size (by default).