# Is there a folder size tool for linux? (web-based or working on console)

Tags: linux, filesystems, console, directory

I have a debian server which has a lot of user folders and I would like to have a tool like [FolderSize](http://www.id-design.com/software/whatsize) application in Mac, where i can check the filesystem by filetype or foldersize (or whatever argument possible to sort) to have a quick look on server storage.

It can be a text-mode application like Midnight Commander or a web based application like Webmin. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[GT5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Isn't **du** enough?

Comment: du is pretty powerful, but GT5 kind of tool was what i was looking for. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't think one invocation of du is enough, but multiple ones might be. Look at the documentation of '-S' for example. dirent size can be significant for things like Maildirs with high churn. I've just freed about 100M by creating a new directory; moving all the files from an older one into it; removing the older one; renaming the new one.

Answer (score 6):

I use `ncdu` for this. Console-based, so working anywhere, and very simple to use.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen in Tekzilla a tool, named [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) which runs on several OSes. Actually I haven't tried it out on any Linux yet but on Vista it is great. And it is a Java application therefore it should work on Linux too.

Comment: it works, and it is really cool :)

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/25043/find-largest-directories-files-recursively/25541#25541) for a list of additional options.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ du -sh foldername
408K    foldername

$ man du

du - estimate file space usage

-s, --summarize
         display only a total for each argument

-h, --human-readable
          print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

it's manual but it works wonders if you hook it into a script

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [agedu](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/agedu/). From the description "It does basically the same sort of disk scan as du, but it also records the last-access times of everything it scans. Then it builds an index that lets it efficiently generate reports giving a summary of the results for each subdirectory, and then it produces those reports on demand. "