# What's a programme that cron's like mlocate, reads like htop and shows me my filesystem usage?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-space-utilization, command-line-interface

Pertinent to this question I just asked [Find files taking up 80% of the space on a Linux Webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/43296/how-does-one-find-which-files-are-taking-up-80-of-the-space-on-a-linux-webserver/43302#43302)

I think a programme like this would be excellent. Up to date info about files & folders on the system and what space they were taking.

You could even throw in some warning info about permissions.

Does something like this exist?

I keep thinking of the windows app Treesize which I used back in '98 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) is a curses interface to du. It's not so good for the batchness you want, but it'll show you what's using the space.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
watch du
```

Or

```
watch df
```

See also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/25043/find-largest-directories-files-recursively/25541#25541). I like [gt5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

It's unix, so you answered your own question: use cron to run a du command and write the output to a file.

For instance:

```
root@zachs:~# cat /etc/cron.d/update-home-sizes 
0 4 * * * root du /home/* --max-depth 1 | sort -n >/home/.sizes
```

keeps a .sizes file in /home updated with how much disk each of my users is using.  Tweak to suit your individual needs, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [agedu](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/agedu/). From the description "It does basically the same sort of disk scan as du, but it also records the last-access times of everything it scans. Then it builds an index that lets it efficiently generate reports giving a summary of the results for each subdirectory, and then it produces those reports on demand. "

It will also supply a url which you can use to navigate your file system such that the age of the files in each directory is obvious.