# How can I find the biggest directories in Unix / Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unix

Is there a way in Unix to see the biggest directories on disk?

I need to know why I'm almost out of space on the server,= and I don't know where most of the space is used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find largest directories/files recursively](http://serverfault.com/questions/25043/find-largest-directories-files-recursively)

Comment: Here is a good one:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/how-do-you-sort-du-output-by-size  - it says to use `du | sort -h` then use `tail` - or, you can use `sort -rh` so the largest are at the beginning and you can use `more` to see it.  This is working great on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in August 2017.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try: `du --max-depth=7 /* | sort -n` - it won't just tell you directories, and there will be duplicates, but it will list everything 7 levels deep and sort them by size order.

Comment: 7 levels all at once might be overwhelming. I would start with `--max-depth=0` (or rather, use `--summarize`/`-s`), and then drill into the largest directories by hand.

Comment: Good point, just chose that number as that's how far I typically end up going before I find something useful.

Comment: what about `du -cs * | sort -n` for an overview of which directory is bigger?

Comment: I prefer: `du -ch | sort -nr | head -10`

Answer (score 80):

My favorite tool for this task is [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu).

[image: ncdu example screen]

Comment: Nice. It works pretty much the way I'd do it by hand (with `du | sort`), but with WAY less typing.

Comment: This is much better. just install ncdu and type ncdu command on the directory you want to analyze, it works very fast.

Comment: never knew about this tool. this is perfect thank you

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to use [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/), which will give you a graphical overview of your disk usage. It can also be used for remote folder (through ssh, ftp,...) to scan the disk usage on a remote server for instance.

**Edit:** If you would like to investigate the disk usage directly on the server with your shell access and not remotely, and you would like a tool more convenient than `du`, you can also have a try with [durep](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/durep) which will generate a report of the disk usage with bar graphs.

Comment: cool, but I only have shell access on my VPS (low RAM)

Answer (score 3):

I usually use something like this:

```
du -ch / | sort
```

You can apply a depth restriction using --max-depth= if you don't want to see past a certain level from your target, like so:

```
du -ch --max-depth=4 /
```

Answer (score 3):

## Find biggest folders and their biggest subfolders successively

I parse through each folder level, to find the root of the problem, like this:

#### iteration 1

```bash
du -h --max-depth=1 -t 1G /Dir0/Dir1 | sort -n | tail -10
```

#### iteration 2

```bash
du -h --max-depth=1 -t 1G /Dir0/Dir1/biggestFolderInDir1 | sort -n | tail -10
```

**-h**: human readable sizes

**-t 1G**: only list directories bigger than 1G

**sort -n**: sort numerically (2G will be considered bigger than 1T)

**tail -10**: only list the last (biggest) 10 items

Manpages: **[du](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/du.1.html)** - **[sort](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/sort.1.html)** - **[tail](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/tail.1.html)**

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try `df` & `du -sh /`. And recursively `du -sh`. Not the best solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

> sudo du / | sort -n

Will give you a quick answer (last entries are largest files/directories)

Comment: Define quick? In my experience this usually takes at least 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`# cd /; du -shb | sort -nr > /root/home/disk-space-report.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I always use syntax like

`du -sm --max-depth=4 /path/i/want/to/drill | sort -nr | head -n 20`.

max-depth and head parameters can vary, of course, but the above would list 20 biggest directories.

Comment: 2G will be considered bigger than 1T

Answer (score 0):

I'm regularly running `du -dak > du-dak.out` at the top of each file system. Then, I can get a graphical display with `xdu < du-dak.out`. This can be done remotely after transferring the du-dak.out file over the network should you only have text access.

http://sd.wareonearth.com/~phil/xdu/